# How can I serve different content to printers than browsers?

Tags: php, apache

I want to be able to detect if it is a printer rather than a browser that is requesting a web page.

I know of User-Agent strings and 'media print' style sheets, however, I want to serve different content, to maybe redirect to a PDF (or not) when a page has been requested 'to print'. Therefore, what is there, if anything, in the header that I can go on to determine if it is (say) a Firefox browser requesting a print page or a Firefox browser requesting a media=screen page?

Comment: Down vote for not considering sensible solutions.

Comment: The browser prints what is already on the screen. It doesn't make a new request for the print job, or the content could be different (think of the results of a form).

Comment: Thanks for answers but no real need for the down votes! I did not realise the browser prints what it already has. I just wanted to know if there was a way to dish out the p-d-f-file version of the same content when going to 'print'.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to detect that the "content is being sent to the printer" from the server side because the browser does not make a separate request in this context.

The only caveat to the above would be that the browser might request the print stylesheet *if it didn't already have that resource in its cache*, so you might be able to use the presence of such a request to determine that the browser did render the content for a printer (note:  not the same thing as printing the content though, since the user could just simply cancel the print dialog)... although you're still stuck because there would be no way to change the content that the browser had already downloaded.

Your best bet is to include a link to the "print version" of the content.

#### EDIT (mostly just for fun):

Now maybe, just maybe, it's possible that you could open a socket connection to the server on the client side, and when the server detects the request for the print stylesheet, it uses a cookie value to identify which client is requesting that resource, and it sends a notification back through the socket to the client giving it the new content to render.

Of course, you're still stuck because:

- This stops working the instant the browser caches the print stylesheet.
- It creates a race condition - will the new content from the server reach the browser before it starts rendering the content for printing?  Or will the browser "freeze" the current view first?
- Even assuming you managed to inject the alternate content when the document was printed... how are you going to change it back when the user closes the print dialog?
- Really, have you tried a "print version" link?

Comment: I believe that the browser will thread block after receiving the print request.

Comment: My page does not print out too well in FF and probably the other browsers, however, the PDF datasheets do print brilliantly with hires images etc. I just wondered if they could be unobtrusively printed without the little printer and pdf icon I have now.

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />`

Then hide stuff you don't want printed with the stylesheet, and display things you do want printed...

---

There is no special user agent string, or any bit of information that is translated to the server when a page is requested to be printed. This operation is purely client-side, thus the only solution is a client side solution. CSS is the way to handle this.

Comment: I'm guessing this got downvoted because it provides a solution that the OP already indicates is not valid.  Your edit helps address the problem a little better, so you get a +1 from me.

Comment: The author never said that they were a problem, but just that he "knows" of them, which made it seem that he just didn't realize they could be used.

Answer (score 0):

When you print a web page, the browser doesn't re-request the page from the server, but merely prints the current content of the page at the time the print command was issued. The only way to really achieve what you're talking about would be to build your own "print" button on the page which would open a new window or alter the page content before using Javascript to issue the print command to the browser.